# How exactly do graduate students collaborate on a research project?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, paper-submission, collaboration

My question can be elaborated as follows: When graduate students work together on a research project, are they usually expected to work on the *same exact things, at the same exact time*, or would it be more reasonable to have a division of labor and divide the work load?

Comment: It's hard to see how the collaboration arrangement won't be different with every collaboration.

Answer (score 2):

It's really like any other collaboration. Presumably the (student) researchers are working together because they have a common interest in a problem and possibly have some complementary expertise that's useful for solving the problem. So they'll interact and as the situation merits it will divide up tasks (or work on some aspects together). There really isn't a single rule for this.

Comment: I can give you a rule: We should avoid people working on same exact things when the product is knowledge/information. It's very inefficient, because making duplicates is extremely easy and cheap once the product is finished.

Comment: @Trylks:  It's not (necessarily) inefficient if they work on the exact same things _together_.

Comment: @TaraB your concept for "exact same things" is not *exact*. ;)

Comment: @Trylks your statement doesn't make sense in my domain, for example, where two students might be collaborating on proving a theorem. They don't necessarily have complementary expertise and are in fact working on the exact same thing: sometimes it's just the give-and-take of an interaction that leads to a new result.

Comment: @Suresh it's a matter of definitions, granularity, atomicity and "exact same thing". Several developers may be working on the same software project, several of them may be using the exact same computer (two are recommended in extreme programming) or all of them may be typing at the same time (e.g. w/ screenhero) but I wouldn't say that they are doing the exact same thing. This relates with "The Mythical Man-Month" e.g. if one guy takes 1h to make a hole 1m diameter and 10m deep, and 10h for a hole 1m diameter and 10 meter deep, how long will take 10 men for a hole 1m diameter and 10m deep?

Comment: @Suresh in short, if there is give-and-take, they are not doing the exact same thing, because if they were doing the exact same thing then there would be nothing to give and nothing to take.

Comment: @Trylks:  If two people work on, say, proving a mathematical theorem together, by talking to each other and bouncing ideas around, it really can often go a lot quicker than either of them working on it alone, and I would find it a bit odd to say they are not working on the exact same thing.

Comment: @TaraB I was going to say the same thing but didn't want to go swirling down into a morass of pedant :)

Comment: The guy in this picture is not me, because if he was me, this would not be a picture. Call me odd, I would not say that's the exact same thing. In the same theorem, yes, are theorems the atomic level in maths? Are they the maximum granularity? Definitively not. Theorems are sustained by lemmas, propositions, definitions, and each one of them has a formulation, composed of several statements, composed of several symbols, and a proof, composed of several inference steps, that can traverse a path or another, etc.

Comment: In short, you can say it's odd to consider a different holistic level than "theorem", IMHO, it's wrong to consider "theorem" as the most basic holistic level in which maths (or work in maths) is divided or composed into and I would say that we are not speaking about maths here as much as we are speaking about information systems and how to model a domain (in this case formal sciences). I'd suggest to leave it here, you seem to be more focused on explaining me your experience (which I've understood from the start) rather than understanding my point. Further comments can only be futile this way.

Comment: @Suresh:  Probably a wise decision. =]